# Abel–Ruffini theorem, connection to nested radicals

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, nested-radicals

I hope someone can help me with understanding the Abel–Ruffini theorem, especially the connection to nested radicals. I do know the proof based on Galois theory, but I wondered if this text which is appended is really correct? It gives a complete different approach to the topic than Galois theory. I would be thankful if anyone could confirm that this text is completely correct or if not, point out mistakes that this person who wrote this text has made (bad English has made me suspicious).

Edit: The main argument seems to be that a radical of form described in equation (12) cannot be used to solve polynomials of degree 5 or higher. It is claimed that this is not possible, cause you cannot handle 5 degrees of freedom (a,b,c,d,e in x^5+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e). The question remains if this reasoning is correct. For more details have a look at the text.

[image: text]

Comment: I quickly gave up trying to figure out what the argument was supposed to be.

Comment: I think the argument is that a root of a polynomial of degree 5 or higher cannot be expressed as such a radical described in (12)

Comment: Possibly. But that is such a random form to require.

Comment: But I think this text has some mistakes, cause in (12) the second c should rather be an s, otherwise the rest does not make sense. The thing with this radicals is that if you define them to be x you find x itself again in that radical and that would only apply if this c is a s.

Comment: Yeah it is quite random, but I am not even sure if this text is correct at all. I mean theoretically it should not be hard to pick a special case of radicals and see that it is not possible to solve with them a polynomial of degree 5 or higher, but I am not sure if this is all correct and rigours